# How to revoke / cancel an iOS push notification if its read on another device?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In apple messages and slack, if you read a message on another device, the push notification will magically disappear from your phone. How can I do this? I can't find any information about this in the documentation.